# console.log Stripping Carriage Returns (displaying as a literal ↵)

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to write a JavaScript function that prints a string to the console via console.log. However, the string has carriage returns in it, which show up as a literal ↵ character instead of creating a new line. Is this a limitation of console.log, or is there a way around this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm actually trying to print this function inside an object. Something like:

```
function blah() {
};
console.log({ "function" : blah });
```

I didn't think to mention it initially, but after trying crowjonah's solution I realize that console.log apparently treats strings passed directly differently from strings passed inside another object.

Comment: What are you using for your carriage return? \r\n seems to work for me in the chrome console and with console.log()

Comment: \n, but there's an additional constraint I didn't think to mention; see edited question.

Comment: It'd help if we knew what `blah()` was.

Answer (score 6):

Chrome will render `\n` as `↵` when printing objects that contain multi-line strings. However, you can simply double-click on the logged string to see it with proper newlines.

Comment: Unless you get `<string is too large to edit>`. (－‸ლ)

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of console. but you can create a work around:

```
function multiLineLog(msg) {
    msg = msg.split(/[\r\n]+/g);
    for (var a=0; a < msg.length; a++) console.log(msg[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `\n` in the log message wherever you'd like there to be a line return.

```
console.log('first line \nsecond line');
```

if the "carriage returns" are html elements, like `<br>`, you can run a replace on the string to do it automatically

```
var newLogMessage = multiLineLogMessage.replace('<br>', '\n');
console.log(newLogMessage);
```

Comment: Does this only work if you pass the string directly to console.log? I'm trying something like `function blah() {}; console.log({ "function" : blah });` and it just replaces the newlines with literal carriage return characters again :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of [SReject's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589697/1762224):

```js
const log = line => console.log(line);
const multiLineLog = msg => msg.split(/[\r\n]+/g).forEach(log);

const data = { a: { b: { c: null } } };

multiLineLog(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```